# Get all imported library in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

What is the simple way to get all the share libraries that Linux process loaded with C code?

Comment: does that help? https://superuser.com/questions/310199/how-to-see-the-currently-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux

Comment: Run `ldd executable` — maybe via `system()` or maybe via `popen()` and `pclose()`.  However, that won't pick up dynamically loaded libraries, so it may not be what you need — and the question on SU may help more.